# Jenkins Agent disconnected related to Java

Tags: java, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Our team been experienced jenkins slave agent disconnection issue.
This problem happens frequently in packer baking machine.

During the slave machine running, it will get disconnected at any point.
and the error message is:

```
07:31:11  Cannot contact EC2 (ThomsonReutersEC2) - PackerAgent (i-05b6a0894cdfcd6fd): hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@11a64065:EC2 (ThomsonReutersEC2) - PackerAgent (i-05b6a0894cdfcd6fd)": Remote call on EC2 (ThomsonReutersEC2) - PackerAgent (i-05b6a0894cdfcd6fd) failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
08:08:32  Could not connect to EC2 (ThomsonReutersEC2) - PackerAgent (i-05b6a0894cdfcd6fd) to send interrupt signal to process
[Pipeline] }
08:08:32  EC2 (ThomsonReutersEC2) - PackerAgent (i-05b6a0894cdfcd6fd) was marked offline: Connection was broken: java.io.EOFException
08:08:32    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2759)
08:08:32    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3234)
08:08:32    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:913)
08:08:32    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:375)
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:142)
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:128)
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
08:08:32  Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
08:08:32    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
```

**We did some to improve this situation, which is make jenkins slave agent using same JAVA version, like java8 as jenkins master. This approach did decrease the chances of disconnection issue, but the problem still exists.**

**Here is the connection msg of java launch jenkins remoting agent, so far we did not find change remoting agent version help**

```
INFO: Launching remoting agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection):  java -Xdebug -Xmx2048m  -jar /tmp/remoting.jar -workDir /var/jenkins
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Remoting version: 4.3
This is a Unix agent
Evacuated stdout
Agent successfully connected and online
```

We been monitoring the box which has this problem, so far, not too much logs can tell the error and no memory or CPU high usage found.